# How to define a custom folder structure in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

I defined a custom folder structure in my sample Ionic 3 app.

```
pages/
   ...
modules/
   ...
```

For some reason, it works normally when in device/emulator but *not* with prod environment. e.g.

> npm run build --prod --aot

**Error**

> Unexpected value 'null' exported by the module 'ListModule in .../src/modules/list/list.module.ts'

**Full code**: https://github.com/dragGH102/ngrx-ionic-with-ngrx-and-multiple-modules

Comment: Where your `modules/` folder in that git repo?

Comment: @Duannx under /src. I updated the repo, there was some issue with the commit. Also, new repo URL: https://github.com/dragGH102/ngrx-ionic-with-ngrx-and-multiple-modules

Comment: try to change `IonicModule.forRoot(ListComponent)` --> `IonicPageModule.forChild(ListComponent)`

Comment: @Duannx unfortunately same error, I pushed the updated version. Can you perhaps try to clone it and just run it? It's ready to run ;) (except installing node modules)

Comment: I don't know why you `export default class ListComponent`. But just remove `default ` and change `import ListComponent` to `import {ListComponent}`.

Comment: that's a practice I've learned from React (default export) and also named exports are better for debugging. why do you suggest not to do either of these? (besides this, I'll try as you suggested even though I'd like to know why)

Comment: To be honest, i don't know how does it solve the problem. I see your way is not familiar in Ionic and i just change it to normal way and it works .

Comment: yes, you're right. it seems to work. once I built it, how do I run it? so I can test if the app works correctly and I'll accept the answer (which I encourage you to post) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem just change the way you export to ionic normal way:

```
export class ListComponent
```

And import it like this:

```
import { ListComponent } from "./components/list/list";
```

To run your app in device, use following command:

```
ionic cordova run android
(or)  ionic cordova run android --livereload (For live reload)
```

You can change android with ios.
 To use live reload, make sure your device and your server (laptop) is connect in same wifi address. See more about [Ionic CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)

Comment: how do I test the app whish was built in the previous step and stored. in www/ etc. , not at runtime with "run"?

Comment: What platform do you want to test? android or ios or browser

Comment: Android platform

Comment: Since you use android platfrom, after `ionic cordova build android` command finish you will see the location of .apk file in terminal. It usually is: `platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk`